# Is it possible to filter OMS dashboard on workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-oms

I am trying to build dashboards which can be shared accross several Azure OMS workspaces. I want to be able to add a filter on the dashboard in order to select the right workspace.

This would avoid to have to build the same dashboard 20 times im different wokspaces.

I know that is is possible to select any visible workspace from a request using the :

```
workspace("<workspace_name>")
```

function but I am unable to get a filter on my OMS dashboards to switch workspace.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the dashboard only supports the simple time filter, and not support other filters.

You may raise a user voice to the related team and hope they can add such feature in the future.

Comment: I cannot actually say that this his "helpful", do you have any explicit reference which states that ?

Comment: @H.C.Lefevre, actually I cannot find a reference doc(I suspect there is no such doc). I generated a lot of dashboards previously, the only filter I can find is `time filter`.